# Программирование в IDE на широкоформатном мониторе?

Tags: монитор, ide

Хочу заказать широкоформатный монитор диагональю дюймов в 29, с каждым днем маленькое окошко текстового редактора в IDE раздражает меня все больше и больше. У кого нибудь был подобный опыт? Какие подводные камни? Как следует правильно выбирать монитор, чтобы на него можно было по долгу смотреть?

Comment: Сам хочу в песпективе купить широкий формат. Ну что тут советовать... чтобы глаза не уставали, чтобы был с хорошим, приятным дизайном и создавал чувство комфорта. Выберите по душе, купите и пользуйтесь с удовольствием!

Comment: - Имхо, два одинаковых монитора `24"` или связка `24" + 19"` предпочтительнее, поскольку сразу же вырабатывается привычка разделять контексты работы между мониторами и свитчиться между ними проще, нежели на одном мониторе.
- То есть, скажем, серчишь что-то в браузере - повернул голову налево, хочешь вернуться к разработке - повернул голову направо. На мой взгляд, неплохой приобретенный рефлекс :)
- Если говорить с технической точки зрения, то `IPS` матрица - это мастхев, а все остальное уже можно выбирать на свой вкус и цвет.

Comment: @igumnov, не читайте бред от пользователя @Genchik. Чтобы комфортно было работать с широкоформатным дисплеем, просто соблюдайте обычные правила охраны труда при работе за компьютером.

Прочитайте законодательный акт СанПиН 2.2.2/2.4.1340-03 «Гигиенические требования к ПЭВМ и организации работы».

Из своего опыта могу сказать, что лучше 2 монитора с меньшей диагональю дисплея, чем один но большой; сидя перед монитором, верхняя часть монитора должна находится на уровне глаз или чуть ниже (угол ~30 градусов).

Comment: Про поворот головы интересно :))

Comment: Бред оО Вы может не знаете о боковом излучении? 2 монитора, какое у Вас зрение?

Comment: Когда смотрите сверху вниз на изображение на экране, то получается, что глаза слегка прикрыты верхними веками. Слезная пленка менее испаряется. А чем меньше она испаряется, тем меньше риск покраснения глаз, рези в глазах, "песка" в глазах...

Comment: Это я знал ) а вообще для работы конечно 2 рабочие области лучше, но опять же излучение, без открытой форточки очень даже неплохо вредит.

Comment: Кактус на стол. Это работает - инфа 100%.

Comment: А так же электромагнитное излучение и пр. На то существуют 15-20 минутные перерывы, через каждый час работы за компьютером. Это время необходимо использовать активно. Прогулка/гимнастика для глаз...

В общем необходимо читать СанПин чтобы минимизировать вред для здоровья.

Comment: IPS матрица хороша для просмотра видео. Для текста и тем более его написания не подходит, слишком ярко, слишком контрастно, в общем не комфортно.

Comment: Кот мешает зарубить яркость и контрастность настройками монитора?

Comment: > Кактус на стол. Это работает - инфа 100%.

Вранье. Без шапочки из фольги кактус не работает!

Comment: Еще можно капроновые чулки на экран натянуть, неплохо гасит всплески излучения. Говорят, совместимо со всеми моделями кактусов.

Comment: Лично я не люблю широкоформатные т.к. начинает не хватать высоты. Особенно на небольшом ноутбуке, конечно. Приходится панель задач передвигать в сторону... Строчки в программах по 200 символов всё равно не нужны - будут другие условия - будешь скроллить, не дай бог :) . 
Правда, должен признать, что на двух широкоэкранных 1920*1080 работалось замечательно. 
Два монитора ещё лучше тем, что можно одним нажатием развернуть окно на половину области... Только в Windows 7 сделали win+<-/->.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня 2 монитора по 22". Очень удобно, пространства хоть отбавляй. В Visual Studio я раздвигаю окно на 2 монитора, делаю сплит рабочих областей. Немного не удобно в том плане, что иногда приходится переводить взгляд с одной области на другую, но это совсем пустяк по сравнению с реальным комфортом. Насчет большого монитора на 29" я не советовал бы, потому что разрешение экрана также останется 1920х1080 (если он конечно не особенный хD), а **впервую очередь для меня важно количество точек**, а не "здоровый" монитор. Плюс к этому можно наладить дебаг мультимониторных приложений (если такая необходимость имеется). К тому же по цене 2 монитора по 22" будут сравнимы, а если уже монитор имеется, то выгода очевидна. Знаю только, что 29" нужны дизайнерам, которые постоянно вглядываются в мелочи. Плюс я купил новый монитор с IPS, старый с TN-Film -- разницы практически никакой. Все может быть сугубо индивидуально, но я поступил так и ничуть не жалею.

Comment: У самого два монитора 24+19. Правда 19 подключена параллельно к маку (к сожалению, приходится иногда и  на нем немножко работать).
Очень удобно с двумя. Раньше ютился на 29 - не удобно, не хватает захвата глазами и окна постоянно приходилось подгонять.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас работаю на 17" ноуте, выставляю очень крупные шрифты в IDЕ чтобы меньше уставали глаза, и на таком разрешении уже такой диагонали не хватает - приходится таскать много чего по экрану сразу (IDE, браузер, пр...). Пробовал работать на 27" с такими же крупными шрифтами - идеально и не так грузит как два монитора поставленные рядом (покрывают все боковое зрение). Думаю перейти на 27"

Comment: а сидите случайно не за полтора метра от монитора?:)

Comment: Нет)   Но 27" конечно отодвигал где-то на метр от головы. Очень удобно

Comment: Мне бы не хватало пикселов для работы.